# Why Bytes Sent to Transport/sec is different on different replicas?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, distributed-availability-groups

I am troubleshooting latency for a specific replica in a Distributed AG setup (with 2 remote replicas).
Looking at perfmon I see clear indication as to why one replica shows delay. I see Bytes Sent to Transport/sec is in sync with one replica (*Red & Purple lines*) - but not on the other. (*Green Line*).

I was wondering what could contribute to this behaviour. I checked there is no delay at Flow Control Gates.

[image]

Edit:
SQL Server Version is 2019 (CU22)

Answers to questions from comments:

- Is this for the same AG and a different distributed replica?
  Different AGs?

> This is for one single AG only.

- Where are the replicas?

> All 3 distributed replicas are in different DCs across the globe. Each AG has 2 nodes (sync mode).

- Are the distributed replicas setup the same (sync/async)?

> Yes, both are ASYNC

- Is the hardware the same?

> YES

- Are all of the databases on the forwarder side ok?

> YES

Comment: What is your SQL Server version? As I recall, AGs change a lot between versions.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention, Updated now. Thanks @J.Mini!

Comment: Is this for the same AG and a different distributed replica? Different AGs? Where are the replicas? Are the distributed replicas setup the same (sync/async)? Is the hardware the same? Are all of the databases on the forwarder side ok?

Comment: Answers updated in question.

Comment: "All 3 distributed replicas are in different DCs across the globe."  what is the connectivity between each (include latency and bandwidth).

Comment: I did try to do NW benchmarking using nttcp as suggested in one of MS Docs for AG tuning. It shows both sites give 100 MB/s with latency of 144ms and 176ms.

Comment: Can you label the perfmon output? Is the other replica falling behind? Is the connection flow controlled at any level?

Comment: I am not aware of any flow coltroling in between. Interestingly, I did failover on AG replica with issue (On local AG, from primary to secondary) and it is now not showing spikes! Weird.

Comment: I have tried to reproduce this issue by performing failovers - no luck till now.